# How i can retrieve data in my linux virtual device driver?

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have to implement virtual device driver, that will calculate sin of specified angle.

I found [article](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html?page=2) how to write hello-world driver, it works nice, when i call `cat` on it.

But to calculate sin, i need to transfer some data to my driver. Which solution is most painless?

Should i first of all read all input data in separate method, remember it somewhere and then calculate & output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most painless solution would probably be to implement a `ioctl`.

The `cat` in the linked example uses `read()`, that is nice when your device generates data, such as a mouse or a video camera, but when a device replies to commands a `ioctl` is more appropriate: you send a command `GET_SIN` with an angle as argument and get a reply with the answer.

The alternative would be to `write()` the angle and then `read()` the solution: far more complicated, because there may be several processes reading and writing at the same time and it would be a mess!

BTW, beware! AFAIK, the kernel is not allowed to use floating point arithmentic, nor to link to `-lm`, so you will have to implement the sine as a fix-point integer function, maybe using a table...

Comment: Wow! Thank a lot for reply. But how i will be able to communicate with my driver via command line? Or there could be only programming interface, and i will have to make separate program to work with?

Comment: @avasin: Ah!, that is the drawback! There is no generic command for `ioctl`. In order to communicate with the driver you will have to write a small user-space utility. Just a `main()` program that parses `argv[1]`, sends it to the `ioctl` and prints back the result.

Comment: i found, that ioctl negative values can be treated as error status. So, i have to implement read & write interface.

Comment: @avasin: Well, `ioctl` can get a pointer, either to a single value or a struct. Or given that the sine of an angle is between -1 and 1, you could normalize the output to (0, 2) and correct it in user-land.